# Performance Issue On MySQL DataBase

Tags: mysql

I have table contains around 14 million records, and I have multiple SP's contain Dynamic SQL, and these SP's contain multiple parameters,and I build Indexes on my table, but the problem is I have a performance Issue, I tried to get the Query from Dynamic SQL and run it, but this query takes between 30 Seconds to 1 minute, my query contains just select from table and some queries contain join with another table with numeric values in where statement and grouping and order by.

I checked status result, I found the grouping by takes all time, and I checked Explain result, It's using right index.

So what I should doing to enhance my queries performance.

Thanks for your cooperation.

-- EDIT, Added queries directly into question instead of comment.

```
SELECT 
      CONCAT(column1, ' - ', column1 + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS DateRange, 
      cast(SUM(column2) as SIGNED)  AS Alias1 
   FROM
      Table1
         INNER JOIN Table2 DD 
            ON Table1.Date = Table2.Date 
   WHERE 
          Table1.ID = 1 
      AND (Date BETWEEN 20110101 AND 20110201) 
   GROUP BY 
      MONTH(column1) 
   ORDER BY 
      Alias1 ASC 
   LIMIT 0, 10;
```

and this one:

```
SELECT 
      cast(column1 as char(30)) AS DateRange, 
      cast(SUM(column2) as SIGNED) 
   FROM 
      Table1 
         INNER JOIN Table2 DD 
            ON Table1.Date = Table2.Date 
   WHERE 
          Table1.ID = 1 
      AND (Date BETWEEN 20110101 AND 20110102) 
   GROUP BY 
      column1 
   ORDER BY 
      Alias1 ASC 
   LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: If you want us to help, show us the query and the explain results.

Comment: My query like below queries: SELECT  CONCAT(column1, ' - ', column1 + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS DateRange, 
          cast(SUM(column2) as SIGNED)         
    FROM Table1   
 INNER JOIN Table2 DD ON Table1.Date = Table2.Date 
WHERE Table1.ID = 1 AND (Date BETWEEN 20110101 AND 20110201) 
    GROUP BY MONTH(column1)
  ORDER BY column2 ASC
  LIMIT 0, 10;

Comment: and this one: SELECT  cast(column1 as char(30)) AS DateRange, 
          cast(SUM(column2) as SIGNED)         
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 DD ON Table1.Date = Table2.Date 
WHERE Table1.ID = 1 AND (Date BETWEEN 20110101 AND 20110102) 
    GROUP BY  column1
  ORDER BY column2 ASC
  LIMIT 0, 10;

Comment: @user977042, the queries as stated will not run, thery have syntax errors and ambiguous column references. Can you fix the code so that all columns named have a table.prefix?

Comment: I would qualify the "Date" column in the where clause to that of table1, and have a compound index on ID and Date

Comment: I already have an index on these columns.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(column1, ' - ', column1 + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS DateRange  <<--error? never mind
  , cast(SUM(column2) as SIGNED)
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 DD ON Table1.Date = Table2.Date 
WHERE Table1.ID = 1 
  AND (Date BETWEEN 20110101 AND 20110201) 
GROUP BY MONTH(column1)    <<-- problem 1. 
ORDER BY column2 ASC       <<-- problem 2.
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

1. If you `group by` a function MySQL cannot use an index. You can speed this up by adding an extra column `YearMonth` to the table1 that contains the year+month, put an index on that and then `group by yearmonth`.
2. The order by does not make sense. You are adding `column2`, ordering by that column serves no purpose. If you `order by yearmonth asc` the query will run much faster and make more sense.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I order By Alias for cast(SUM(column2) as SIGNED) not on column2, sorry for this mistake.